# Is there a way to set "rules" for string matching in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, nlp, fuzzyjoin

I've been scratching my head trying to find a way to solve this problem without having to get into NLP and start training models. I have 2 rather large data sets that should be able to be matched by name, but the spellings and syntax of them are slightly different, easy enough for a human to understand, but complex enough that my fuzzy matching and levenshtein edit distances cannot. There is a large amount of duplicates in the data set, but enough where I cannot manually map them, so I am trying to create "rules" around what to match. Would a package such as FuzzyWuzzy allow more bespoke elements to solve this? Example below, thanks!

```
a <- c("The City of New York", "The City of New York", "Los Angeles City", "The State of California", "The State of California")

b <- c("New York City", "New York City", "Los Angeles", "California State", "CA State")
```

The closest I've gotten so far in matching the data sets is fuzzy string matching, but this only works decently well, and still misses a large chunk or makes quite a bit of errors as I increase the max edit distance.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

a <- as.tibble(a)
b <- as.tibble(b)
stringdist_inner_join(x = a, y = b, max_dist = 3, method = 'LV', ignore_case = T)
```

The dataset as a bit more depth than that. I was hoping to make a "rule" of some sort that "The City of New York" always equals "New York City", but I'm not sure if there's a smarter way to go about this. I hope this specific text example helps. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: How many city you have and how many variance you may have for each city? Sometimes, the best way is the simplest way, have a mapping list.

Comment: @SinhNguyen there's a few hundred unique strings. I'm figuring this may be the best way to go, thanks!